# Vuforia/Android Studio: How can I change the vertex of 3D model(.obj)?

Tags: android, vuforia

I am developing an android application for augmented reality using with Vuforia SDK. Vuforia uses teapot model as a sample. I want to change it with different 3D models.

First of all, I read [here](http://v%20-47.434967%20-14.179193%2041.621128%20v%20-47.290016%20-32.284641%2030.312384%20v%20-50.046577%20-28.483284%2028.886757%20v%20-48.418915%20-26.21903%2033.460499%20v%20-46.001163%20-30.491556%2033.941067%20v%20-56.681168%20-27.034826%2015.786369%20v%20-56.716259%20-23.535177%2019.358313%20v%20-54.001244%20-27.203417%2022.164679%20v%20-54.523552%20-29.940945%2018.01193%20%20vt%200.162396%200.657685%200%20vt%200.693161%200.224146%200%20vt%200.926491%200.934053%200%20vt%200.587396%200.694719%200%20vt%200.312997%200.011653%200%20vt%200.493802%200.29425%200%20vt%200.571748%200.898927%200%20vt%200.524454%200.694721%200%20vt%200.919639%200.171535%200%20vt%200.375939%200.011657%200) but could not understand how I change it.

I downloaded some models as .obj and opened with notepad.I can reach the vertex of model. For example,

```
v -47.434967 -14.179193 41.621128
v -47.290016 -32.284641 30.312384
v -50.046577 -28.483284 28.886757
v -48.418915 -26.21903 33.460499
v -46.001163 -30.491556 33.941067
v -56.681168 -27.034826 15.786369
v -56.716259 -23.535177 19.358313
v -54.001244 -27.203417 22.164679
v -54.523552 -29.940945 18.01193

vt 0.162396 0.657685 0
vt 0.693161 0.224146 0
vt 0.926491 0.934053 0
vt 0.587396 0.694719 0
vt 0.312997 0.011653 0
vt 0.493802 0.29425 0
vt 0.571748 0.898927 0
vt 0.524454 0.694721 0
vt 0.919639 0.171535 0
vt 0.375939 0.011657 0
```

In Vuforia sample, there is a class which is called "teapot" and has some methods to get vertex of model.

```
 private void setVerts()
    {
        double[] TEAPOT_VERTS = { 11.222200, 0.110300, 20.030291, 10.302300,
                -4.461498, 20.030291, 10.152300, -4.397198, 20.644890,
                11.059500, 0.110900, 20.644890, 11.059500, 0.110900, 20.644890,
                10.152300, -4.397198, 20.644890, 10.326300, -4.471797,
                20.849890, 11.248200, 0.110300, 20.849890, 11.248200, 0.110300,
                20.849890, 10.326300, -4.471797, 20.849890, 10.679500,
                -4.623797, 20.644890, 11.632100, 0.108900, 20.644890,
                11.069200, -4.791098, 20.030291, 12.054700, 0.107300,
...

-21.810101, 1.635499, 11.037194, -19.837999, 1.628499,
                8.929396, -16.952299, 1.617799, 7.150197 };
        mVertBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_VERTS);
        verticesNumber = TEAPOT_VERTS.length / 3;
    }


    private void setTexCoords()
    {
        double[] TEAPOT_TEX_COORDS = { 0.608828, 0.354913, 0.609037, 0.414650,
                0.627128, 0.412296, 0.626946, 0.353747, 0.626946, 0.353747,
                0.627128, 0.412296, 0.645212, 0.412296, 0.645121, 0.354854,
                0.645121, 0.354854, 0.645212, 0.412296, 0.665996, 0.413114,
                0.665992, 0.362321, 0.686991, 0.412965, 0.686888, 0.354543,
                0.609164, 0.471551, 0.627580, 0.470826, 0.627580, 0.470826,
                0.645666, 0.470826, 0.645666, 0.470826, 0.666214, 0.470826,
                0.686992, 0.471343, 0.609037, 0.528447, 0.627786, 0.529284,
...

0.195504, 0.141216, 0.182330, 0.579904, 0.174024, 0.485925,
                0.174243, 0.394528, 0.180175, 0.298414, 0.189013, 0.199932 };
        mTexCoordBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_TEX_COORDS);

    }


    private void setNorms()
    {
        double[] TEAPOT_NORMS = { -0.964496, 0.067011, -0.255454, -0.865037,
                0.431362, -0.256198, -0.914727, 0.312709, -0.255904, -0.964979,
                -0.059958, -0.255382, -0.734604, 0.051028, 0.676574, -0.657992,
                0.328017, 0.677828, -0.696209, 0.237894, 0.677274, -0.735103,
                -0.045689, 0.676414, 0.470823, -0.032731, 0.881620, 0.421539,
                -0.210047, 0.882148, 0.608717, -0.267273, 0.747013, 0.665522,
...

0.773683, 0.222907, 0.593066, 0.590633, 0.196416, 0.782671,
                0.516476, 0.182725, 0.836579 };
        mNormBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_NORMS);
    }


    private void setIndices()
    {
        short[] TEAPOT_INDICES = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9,
                10, 10, 11, 8, 11, 10, 12, 12, 13, 11, 1, 14, 15, 15, 2, 1, 5,
                16, 17, 17, 6, 5, 9, 18, 19, 19, 10, 9, 10, 19, 20, 20, 12, 10,
                14, 21, 22, 22, 15, 14, 16, 23, 24, 24, 17, 16, 18, 25, 26, 26,
                19, 18, 19, 26, 27, 27, 20, 19, 21, 28, 29, 29, 22, 21, 23, 30,
...

814, 816, 815, 817, 817, 818, 816, 819, 765, 768, 768, 820,
                819, 820, 768, 770, 770, 821, 820, 821, 770, 772, 772, 822,
                821, 822, 772, 774, 774, 823, 822 };
        mIndBuff = fillBuffer(TEAPOT_INDICES);
        indicesNumber = TEAPOT_INDICES.length;
    }
```

My mind is very blind and I really do not know what I do.

Can you help me?

Thanks all

Comment: It is not very clear what it is you are asking - you seemed to understand what's related to what you want to change. Indeed, the collection of numbers that appear in the .obj file is what you need for rendering the model. If you want another 3d model, you need to replace these arrays.

Comment: Actually I do not know how I change the arrays. It looks like complex for me.

Comment: No one said it is simple - but it actually has nothing to do with Vuforia. Go and learn how 3d models are rendered and what these arrays represent. All the Vuforia guys did was to take the numbers from an .obj file (generated with some 3D studio) and put them in arrays, which the OpenGL renderer uses to render the 3d model...